# Loop in assembly language MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I was trying to create a for loop in assembly to print out all integers from 0 to N-1. For some reason it breaks and creates an infinite loop. Any ideas why? I am using visual studio 2013 masm

```
.data
x           DWORD   0
y           DWORD   0


.code
    main:nop
        invoke version
        invoke readInteger
        add x, eax
        cmp eax, y
        je done

    increase:
        invoke writeInteger, y
        inc y
        cmp y, eax
        jg increase

    done:
        invoke writeInteger, x

        invoke ExitProcess,0

    end main
```

Comment: Use VS's debugger to single-step and watch registers, then you will know why.  But probably `writeInteger` clobbers `eax`, which is normal for most calling conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*writeInteger* will destroy the contents of `EAX` and so you can't readily use it in `cmp y, eax`

Even with that corrected will the loop not work because you need to go back to *increase* when the y variable is **less than x**

Because you start y at zero and increment it, all numbers involved will (need to) be positive

If the input is zero, you should display nothing since the input expresses a **count**!

Putting all together, this is a solution:

```
 invoke   readInteger
 test     eax, eax
 jz       exitNow
 mov      x, eax                ;x=[1,2GB-1]
increase:
 invoke   writeInteger, y
 inc      y
 mov      eax, x
 cmp      y, eax
 jne      increase
exitNow:
 invoke   ExitProcess,0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the solution. What's the difference between cmp and test? Shouldn't eax and eax be always equal to each other therefore skip to exitNow?

Comment: @RomanProcházkaJr. The `test` instruction performs a bitwise AND operation on its operands and sets the flags accordingly. Since in this case (`test eax, eax`) the destination operand and the source operand are the same, the zero flag will reflect if `eax` is zero or not. Alternatively it would be perfectly fine to write instead: `cmp eax, 0` `je exitNow`. This alternative would however consume 1 extra byte of code.